# How can i put multiple line of "if elif " in one line Python

Tags: python

This is my code and i want to put this all in one line:

```
def GetKey(self, key):

    if key == "externalCode":
        return "ExternalCode"
    elif key == "name":
        return "Name"
    elif key == "description":
        return "Description"
    elif key == "remind-indays":
        return "RemindInDays"
    elif key == "is-delegate-supported":
        return "IsDelegateSupported"
    elif key == "escalation":
        return "Escalation"
```

Comment: Put the mappings in a dictionary.

Comment: i want to put this all in one line, it looks a lot of line of code.

Comment: Switch not exist in python i think

Comment: If you have all those relations in a dictionary, then the one line would be `return mydict[key]`.

Comment: I.T Delinquent can you help me to convert it in python switch?

Comment: @FarazKhan Python doesn't have `switch`, you just said that.

Comment: Do you want to know out of curiosity? Or do you need to solve this problem? If it's the second one, then that can be done as: `def GetKey(key):return (''.join(s.title() for s in key.split('-')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def stackflow(x):
    key = {
        "externalCode": "ExternalCode",
        "name": "Name",
        "description": "Description",
        "remind-indays": "RemindInDays",
        "is-delegate-supported": "IsDelegateSupported",
        "escalation": "Escalation"
    }
    return key[x]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary.

```
key_map = {"externalCode": "ExternalCode", "name": "Name", "description": "Description", "remind-indays": "RemindInDays", "is-delegate-supported": "IsDelegateSupported", "escalation": "Escalation"}

def GetKey(self, key):
    return key_map[key];
```

This will raise an error if it's given an invalid key. If you really want to return `None` (as your function does), use the `dict.get()` method.

```
def getKey(self, key):
    return key_map.get(key)
```

Comment: Why use try/except when there's a [convenience method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on dicts for this already...

Comment: @PyPingu Good point, I've update the answer to show multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use a dict instead of your function:

GET_KEY = {
    "externalCode": "ExternalCode",
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "remind-indays": "RemindInDays",
    "is-delegate-supported": "IsDelegateSupported",
    "escalation": "Escalation"}

GET_KEY.get("externalCode")
```

output:

```
'ExternalCode'
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped to make it easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Improved based on suggestions.

```
word = 'name'
d = {'externalCode': 'ExternalCode', "name": "Name", "description": "Description"}

if word in d:
    word = d[word]
print(word)
```

Comment: Why use a loop when you can just use `d[word]`?

Comment: @Barmar How would you handle the exception when your word isn't in the dict?

Comment: Thanks, u solved my problem. Now my code looks perfect and clean :)


 def GetKey(self, key):

        d = {'externalCode': 'ExternalCode', "name": "Name", "description": "Description", "is-delegate-supported":"IsDelegateSupported"}
        return d[key]

Comment: @ShwetaChandel Either `if word in d:` or `try/except`.

Comment: See how I do it in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I try to avoid try/except. But other alternative is better.

Comment: Or you could just use the builtin [`dict.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) method designed exactly for this purpose...

Comment: Probably the best solution is to let it signal an error, since another key probably shouldn't be given in the first place.